# AngularJS $resource DELETE item in collection

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-resource

I have an ASP.NET Web Api (1) controller with GET, POST and DELETE actions. I am calling this from an Angular 1.2.0 RC3 app with `$resource`. Let's call the controller `Foos`.

I do a GET that returns a list of foos:

```
GET http://localhost:55386/api/foos/123456/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:55386
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
```

where the resource is

```
/api/foos/clientId/recordId
```

Here I am saying **get me a list of foos for client x and record y**

Now, I want to remove a single foo from the list of foos that I received, so I call `$delete`:

```
$scope.delete = function(foo){
    foo.$delete();
}
```

however this results in the following request:

```
DELETE http://localhost:55386/api/foos/123456/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:55386
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
```

This delete is obviously trying to delete the entire list of foos, which makes sence.

My question is, **how do I delete a single foo using Angular's $resource without getting each foo in its own GET request?**

UPDATE:

I could do a `GET /api/foo/1` where the resource is `foo/fooId`, and its equivalent `DELETE /api/foo/1` to delete it but I want to get a list of foos instead of each foo individually.

Comment: http://localhost:55386/api/foos/123456/1 is not clientid=123456 and recordid=1 ?

Comment: so I'm bit confused what's wrong ?

Comment: My question is, with $resource, how do I delete a single foo using Angular's $resource without getting each foo in its own GET request? I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misunderstanding how $`resource` works. I assumed that`foo` knew how to delete itself as it is a `Resource` 'instance' in the following function:

```
$scope.delete = function(foo){
    foo.$delete();
}
```

The correct approach is:

```
$scope.delete = function(foo){
    Api.delete({ 
        id: foo.Id, 
        clientId : $scope.clientId, 
        recordId : $scope.recordId 
    });
}
```

You have to manually tell the `$resource` instance to use the id of foo so that the url includes the foo id and does the following DELETE

```
DELETE http://localhost:55386/api/foos/123456/1/123 HTTP/1.1
```

where 123 is `fooId`

Answer (score 1):

I know that is not the question but you should restangular https://github.com/mgonto/restangular. It is easier to interact with rest services

Comment: Thaks, I'll check it out.