# REST clients for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular, hateoas

I am interested to know what options currently are available to interact with REST Apis from AngularJS.

So far I have used $[resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733076/angularjs-resource-delete-item-in-collection) suggested [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular).

1. What other options are available?
2. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Comment: What's even the reason you don't just use $http?

Comment: I am curious. I did read the other two post in Sam Leach's question but I didn't find the answer to the question he has posted here. What's the word on this?